# iOS- Including different image sizes for different display sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, image, retina-display

I am new to iOS programming and programming in general so this will probably be a fairly easy question to answer for someone who is experienced.

I am making a game using sprite kit and I need to include different background image sizes for the different retina display sizes on the iPhone 4 and 5. I am using a graphics package to create the images in .png format then adding them into the project, the issue I have is that, if I make a 640x1136 size image, it works on the 5, and if I use a 640x960, it works fine on the 4 but leaves blank space around the edge on the 5. (I am running it on the simulator)

If I include two identical images with different names, one for each device, how can I load the right one in? Do I only need high resolution image and can use some code to change how it loads the image in, so that it covers the whole screen without pixelation or loss of quality on both devices?

Any help or advice is appreciated. I apologise if this is a simple question, thanks for your time.

Note:
I found out plenty on the internet about using the @2x suffix for high resolution images, but that's not what I'm looking for. I know how to code for different resolutions, just not two different screen sizes with the same resolution, if that makes any sense.

Comment: You can use Images.xcassets catalog, and specify Devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on iOS 7 SDK which you most likely are, make use of the .xcassets catalogue. It has options for different screen sizes, put the different versions of your image there. And then load image in code.

Comment: Cheers, was the exact solution I needed.

Comment: Commented after some minutes of posting your question.